# Failed Build When Trying To Build Eclipse With Gradlew (Environment Variable)

Tags: batch, java, environment-variables, eclipse, minecraft

So I'm trying to get into Minecraft modding, and I've ran into a problem. I have a batch file with the text:

```
gradlew eclipse
```

this is supposed to setup eclipse instead (it closes really fast) it says Build Failed (there is other red text but not that I can see fast enough). I'm using Forge 1.8.9 MDK Java SE Development Kit 8u5. And I have eclipse (text editor for code) installed.

It turns our I could see fast enough to see that it said JAVA_HOME path variable is pointing to:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191
```

instead of the version I want to use for modding which is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
```

is it fine to change this path?
Should I add the:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
```

onto it or what should I do?

Also I now notice that when I look through my environment variables I don't even see the JAVA_HOME environment variable, but yet it says there is one??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! What I had to do was add a JAVA_HOME environment variable with the path to my JDK